# How to specify date range for search in CGridView in Yii?

Tags: gridview, yii

CGridView provides inbuilt search system but for individual columns. I have a date column in my record and i want to search not only for specific date but for a range of dates. How to do this in Yii?

Comment: How would you look this in raw query?

Comment: you must specify your table structure and the format of the date you store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple ways of doing it. I'm not sure if Yii has something built in for dates, however this is what I would do store your date as time() as its much easier to work with and will help you in the longer run. Once you have the time as epoch, I would have a function that took user input covered it to epoch time. and all you would have to do is use the > or < to search for the range.

In your search function for your model

i would do this for the date field:

$criteria->compare('date',$this->getSwitch($this->date), true);

now inside the model create a new function called getSwitch() or what ever you want to name it.

```
  public function getSwitch($switch) {
   //covert the date they are entering to time() and return that comparison.
   }
```